# What does "at what point" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Moral relativists are usually vague about what is to count as a
> society. For instance, within contemporary Britain there are certainly
> members of subcultures who believe that it is morally acceptable to
> use banned drugs for recreational purposes. **At what point** will a
> relativist be prepared to say that the members of these subcultures
> form a separate society, and so can be said to have their own morality
> which is immune to criticism from other cultures? There is no obvious
> answer to this question.

What does "at what point" mean?

[Philosophy: The Basics]

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "At what point" means "when" or "under what conditions".

More generally "At what point" asks when in a process or sequence , or where in going from one place or thing to another, some distinction is mad, some boundary is crossed. It asks for a dividing point or boundary within a continuum.

Comment: Many thanks! I get it now!